# Hosting a Static website in S3 Bucket Folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to host static websites on S3. I know how to do it using S3 buckets ([Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/static-website-hosting.html))

**Question:**

Can I do it using S3 folder instead of S3 bucket? So that I don't have to create a new bucket when I want to host a static site and simply host it by creating a new folder in the same bucket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to point a custom domain name to the site you are hosting in S3, then the bucket name must match the domain name, so you can't have multiple sites with multiple domains in the same bucket. Also, the static site hosting settings are at the bucket level not the "folder" level. **NOTE:** There is actually no such thing as a folder in S3, just key prefixes.